# CSS3 black shadow

Tags: css, shadow

I have a question about box-shadow, so I have a picture with this effect.

I want to same effect like this image in my Jsfiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/EAb3V/2/

This is my css code :

```
#wrapper{
    background:url("http://ealtinel.com/bg1.jpg") no-repeat;
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
}

#probe{
position: absolute;
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:200px;;
z-index: 9999;
height: 35px;
width: 138px;
background:#fff;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-top: 14px;
border-radius: 25px;
-moz-border-radius: 25px;
-webkit-border-radius: 25px;
transition: width 0.5s;
-moz-transition: width 0.s;
-webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
-o-transition: width 0.5s;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 40px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 40px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 40px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your css, I played around a while with different tweaks and got it as close as I think you will be able to:

http://jsfiddle.net/EAb3V/3/

Here is the css I modified:

Before:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 40px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 40px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 40px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

After:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 25px rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.50);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 25px rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.50);
box-shadow:         0px 1px 25px rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.50);
```

Here is another version I did, I added a 2px border slightly darker then the background:
http://jsfiddle.net/EAb3V/4/

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.40);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 20px rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.40);
box-shadow:         0px 1px 20px rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.40);
border: 2px solid #cd870f;
```

Also there are tools out there to help out, like this one here I find is best for box shadows:
http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/

Comment: I just added another version with a 2px border you might like as well.